# How to de-cumulate variable in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an issue. I have panel of quarterly individual data, which are "annually cumulative", ie. values for 1st quarter are for 1st quarter, values for 2nd quarter are sum for 1st and 2nd, 3rd quarter values are sums for first 3 quarters of the year and 4th quarter are annual sums. How to easily de-cumulate those in dplyr, grouping by id and year?

Comment: Please add an example of your dataset, to understand the data structure. With such a question it is impossible to answer!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we have two years, and in year one sales are 2 per quarter, and in year 2 sales are 3 per quarter, the original is:

```
df = data.frame(quarter = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"), year=c(rep(2017,4),rep(2018,4)), cum_tot= c(2,4,6,8,3,6,9,12))

  quarter year cum_tot
1      Q1 2017       2
2      Q2 2017       4
3      Q3 2017       6
4      Q4 2017       8
5      Q1 2018       3
6      Q2 2018       6
7      Q3 2018       9
8      Q4 2018      12
```

Then we can get the sales per quarter as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(original = c(cum_tot[1], diff(cum_tot)))
```

Or, as per GGamba's comment below:

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(original = cum_tot - lag(cum_tot, default = 0))
```

They both result in:

```
  quarter year cum_tot original
1      Q1 2017       2        2
2      Q2 2017       4        2
3      Q3 2017       6        2
4      Q4 2017       8        2
5      Q1 2018       3        3
6      Q2 2018       6        3
7      Q3 2018       9        3
8      Q4 2018      12        3
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: also `mutate(original = cum_tot - lag(cum_tot, default = 0))` which i think is clearer

Comment: Thanks, that's also a nice solution, I was not aware of the lag function. I included it as an alternative in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great and fast. As I have many objects with ids I needed to group by both id and year.

Comment: You can do group_by(id,year) to group by both.